# How to get the number of stacked slides in reveal.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reveal.js

I'm trying to make a remote to a reveal.js presentation using socket.io.
I want to get the number of slides so I'll be able to change the current slide on the screen.
My problem is that I don't know how to get the stacked slides, I do know how to get the normal one (`Reveal.getState()`) but I don't know if it returns the stacked slides and how.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution,
It turns out that `Reveal.getState()` returns an object with the following properties:

```js
{ indexf: undefined, indexh: 0, indexv: 0, overview: false, paused: false, _proto_: Object }
```

I had to change the `indexh` value to change the horizontal slides and the `indexv` value to change the vertical slides.

**NOTE:**
For those who might use this when adding to the `indexv` it goes to the slide below and when subtracting it goes to the slide above.